# initializing a static const array inside a class - c++

Tags: c++, c++17

Consider the following code, I've marked the important line with `#this` symbol:

```
#include <glad/include/glad/glad.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#ifndef LAMP_H
#define LAMP_H
namespace lmp{

    class genLamp{
        unsigned int lmpVAO;
        static const float flag{1}; //#this is allowed 
        static const float default_shape[]{  //#this is not allowed
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,

        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f
    };

        genLamp(std::string vShaderPath, std::string fShaderPath){
            glGenVertexArrays(1, &lmpVAO);
            glBindVertexArray(lmpVAO);


        }

        unsigned int getVAO(){
            return this->lmpVAO;
        }

    };

}

#endif
```

*First of all*, **why is this even not allowed, what problem is the language trying to prevent by preventing this**? And,

Since the `default_shape` array is going to be the same across objects no matter what, I was trying to share this array by making it static. But, this doesn't seem to be possible.  The only thing I can think of is declaring the variable into a global scope, which is not so good in my case. Does `c++`  have any syntax to declare and initialize `static const arrays` ? I'm compiling with `c++17` in case the information is useful.

EDIT: if possible please also explain @user's answer

Comment: I would suggest `std::array`

Comment: Change const to constexpr.

Answer (score 2):

Make them `inline`. The following code compiles.

```
class Temp {
    inline static const float values[] = { 0.0f, 1.0f };
};
```

Or even better,

```
class Temp {
    constexpr static float values[] = { 0.0f, 1.0f };
};
```

Thanks to John for pointing this out.

Comment: GCC and Clang are also happy if it's `constexpr` instead.

Comment: @user , wow, that actually works, but do you mind please telling me why it didn't work and why it works now

Comment: @JohnZwinck , what do you mean? Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @juztcode I mean replace `const` with `constexpr` and your original code will compile.

Comment: @juztcode, also note that `static constexpr` variables are implicitly `inline`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck , why do you think @user's solution works, also it seems we can't re assign the `values[]` array even if we strip the `const` declaration, do you know why?

Comment: @Evg , why would declaring inline work? What is the logic behind it?

Comment: @juztcode it's in the language specification. Have a read of [const static members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static).